# jQuery handler not being called on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code to call a jquery function when a form is submitted is never being called. I've checked the format of the code over and over again, and everything seems in order.

Any clue how to fix this?
Thanks

HTML:

```
<form class="form" role="form" id="experimentform">
    <label for="name">Study Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Experiment Name" id="name">
    <label for="description">Study Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="4" cols="20" id="description" placeholder="description"></textarea>
    <label for="numparticipants">Number of Participants</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="numparticipants" id="numparticipants">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#experimentform").submit(function(event) {
      alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely cannot put code between `<script></script>` tags while also including an external file within the same `<script>` tag.

Should be...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#experimentform").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note:  Typically, the `.preventDefault()` is the very first item within the function.  See:  [event.preventdefault documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#experimentform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Handler for .submit() called.");
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form" role="form" id="experimentform">
    <label for="name">Study Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Experiment Name" id="name">
    <label for="description">Study Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="4" cols="20" id="description" placeholder="description"></textarea>
    <label for="numparticipants">Number of Participants</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="numparticipants" id="numparticipants">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was such a simple change.

Comment: @user2284725, you're welcome.  Also note:  Typically, the `.preventDefault()` is the very first item within the function.